# Mule - flow returns from Jersey Component

Tags: mule

I have a mule flow which uses Jersey REST component

```
    <flow name="rest-api" doc:name="rest-api">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" path="rest" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <logger message="Message !!!!!!!! #[payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST"> 
        <component class="com.test.api.TestAPI" />
    </jersey:resources>
    <logger message="Message $$$$$$$ #[payload]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

</flow>
```

The object past jersey component is of type "org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter"

How to process this payload? I need to use the message and do some work on the message before returning to the invoker.

## UPDATE (below)

Ref: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jersey+Module+Reference

Sending Jersey response to other flows

If you want to transform or send the request from your jersey component to next resource/flow then you need to use

```
ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse) message.getInvocationProperty("jersey_response");
String messageString = (String) cr.getResponse().getEntity();
message.setPayload(messageString);
```

This will convert org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1 type to String, which you can forward to your next resource.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: The question has been drastically reviewed by the OP (see [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19325892/revisions)), so this answer now looks disconnected. This answer explain how a Jersey resource can interact with other flows.*

To invoke other flows from your resources, you can either:

- use component bindings: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Component+Bindings
- make your component classes `MuleContextAware` then use the MuleClient to perform calls.

This is one of the problems APIkit is solving: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit

Comment: David ... I am seeing the log statement after <jersey:resources> which makes me believe that the message is moving past </jersey:resources>. The message is however of type "org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter".   INFO  2013-10-11 15:03:51,308 [[notifications].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Message $$$$$$$ org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1@6c1e42ac

Comment: Oh, interesting, anyway, don't mess with the message payload as it's the resource response ready to be served back to the caller.

Comment: Messing with the message payload is what is shown in the Mule documentation also :) and ya it ends up with a transformation exception as it expects a message with OutputHandler in the payload, any suggestions on how to use the response coming out from the jersey rest service further in the flow ?

Answer (score 1):

Created the following transformer.It converts the Jersey's Response to String

```
public class JerseyResponseTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer { 
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JerseyResponseTransformer.class);

@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {
    logger.debug("Transfroming Jersey Response to String");
    ContainerResponse cr = (ContainerResponse) message.getInvocationProperty("jersey_response");
    String messageString = (String) cr.getResponse().getEntity();
    message.setPayload(messageString); 
    return message; 
}
```

}